# Convert yuv file to image in C#

Tags: c#, directx, yuv

I have an file name data.yuv ( It's contain image data in YUV format).
What I need to do to convert the file to jpg or bmp image with C# ?

If I save the yuv file to image. It's show an green image. Thus, I  need codes to convert data from yuv to image.

[image]

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917087.aspx

Comment: Above link not work for me :(

Answer (score -1):

Open that file by using a `FileStream` and use the constructor of `Bitmap` to convert the stream to a valid bitmap.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("somefile.yuv", FileMode.Open);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(fs);
```

Comment: This just save it to an image. It's not convert data